# Spring cloud data flow - Micro services deployment

Tags: spring-boot, spring-xd, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-dataflow

Team,
Currently I am working on spring-xd and using as a runtime container for data analytics and yarn jobs.

My questions are

1) Can I leverage the same environment setup which I used for spring-xd? 
2) From the documentation,I read that it can be deployed as micro services, is it using embedded drivers for stream processing? If it is using embedded drivers, can I use it to deploy in a clustered environment with the same infrastructure leveraged for spring-xd?
3) Is there any specific wrappers built for Apache Spark?

My Environment: Spark 1.6.1, Hadoop 2.7.2, zookeeper 3.6.8, redis 3.2, spring-xd-1.3.1

Any help on this specific queries would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I leverage the same environment setup which I used for spring-xd?

Spring Cloud Data Flow (SCDF) relies on [spring-cloud-deployer](https://github.com/spring-cloud?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=deployer) SPI and there are implementations for Cloud Foundry, Apache YARN, Apache Mesos and Kubernetes. Given that you're already having an Hadoop cluster with YARN in use, you could provision the [YARN implementation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-yarn) of the SCDF-server.

> is it using embedded drivers for stream processing?

Not clear what you mean by this. If you're referring to jdbc-drivers; specifically, when using `jdbc` as a sink application, we do embed OSS-friendly drivers, yes.

> If it is using embedded drivers, can I use it to deploy in a clustered environment with the same infrastructure leveraged for spring-xd?

Perhaps answer to #1 covers this. You could leverage the same infrastructure and provision YARN SCDF-server using the [Ambari plugin](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-yarn/blob/master/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-yarn-docs/src/main/asciidoc/getting-started.adoc#deploying-on-ambari).

> Is there any specific wrappers built for Apache Spark?

We have Spark as a [client](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task-app-starters/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-task-spark-client) and [cluster](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task-app-starters/tree/master/spring-cloud-starter-task-spark-cluster) applications. You can [register](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/blob/master/spring-cloud-task-docs/src/main/asciidoc/stream.adoc#spring-cloud-data-flow) them in SCDF to build task/batch pipelines.

Comment: ,Thanks for your convincing answer!!  I meant embedded drivers as spark-driver which is mavenized along with spring-boot which can be deployed in a runtime container. Kindly confirm if this option is feasible and would be great, if you could send me some references.

Comment: I've created some instructions for running a small Spark test app on YARN. See - https://gist.github.com/trisberg/79d50dc46c11c0fb7020c8ccc72d1234#running-a-spark-application-on-yarn-using-spring-cloud-data-flow.  We'll work on improving the docs before the GA release.

Comment: @Thomas, Gone through your samples, really helpful. Also, can you you please post some more examples in Java as well?